# Generating the Next Id when Id is non-AutoNumber

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a table called Employee. The EmpId column serves as the primary key. In my scenario, I cannot make it AutoNumber.

What would be the best way of generating the the next EmpId for the new row that I want to insert in the table?

I am using SQL Server 2008 with C#.

Here is the code that i am currently getting, but to enter Id's in key value pair tables or link tables (m*n relations)

```
Create PROCEDURE [dbo].[mSP_GetNEXTID]
@NEXTID int out,
@TABLENAME varchar(100),
@UPDATE CHAR(1) = NULL

AS
BEGIN
    DECLARE @QUERY VARCHAR(500)

        BEGIN
        IF EXISTS (SELECT LASTID FROM LASTIDS WHERE TABLENAME = @TABLENAME and    active=1)
        BEGIN

            SELECT @NEXTID = LASTID  FROM LASTIDS WHERE TABLENAME = @TABLENAME and active=1

            IF(@UPDATE IS NULL OR @UPDATE = '')
            BEGIN
                UPDATE LASTIDS
                SET LASTID = LASTID + 1 
                WHERE TABLENAME = @TABLENAME
                and active=1
            END

        END
        ELSE
        BEGIN
            SET @NEXTID = 1

            INSERT INTO LASTIDS(LASTID,TABLENAME, ACTIVE)
            VALUES(@NEXTID+1,@TABLENAME, 1)
        END
    END

END
```

Comment: What datatype is the field? Suppose is int?

Comment: Read about `TRIGGER`s

Comment: the datatype of the field is bigint.

Comment: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/sqlcat/archive/2006/04/10/sql-server-sequence-number.aspx

Comment: Do the IDs need to be sequential with no breaks?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Using `MAX(id) + 1` is a bad idea both performance and concurrency wise.

Instead you should resort to [sequences](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff878091.aspx) which were design specifically for this kind of problem.

```
CREATE SEQUENCE EmpIdSeq AS bigint
  START WITH 1
  INCREMENT BY 1;
```

And to generate the next id use:

```
SELECT NEXT VALUE FOR EmpIdSeq;
```

You can use the generated value in a insert statement:

```
INSERT Emp (EmpId, X, Y)
VALUES (NEXT VALUE FOR EmpIdSeq, 'x', 'y');
```

And even use it as default for your column:

```
CREATE TABLE Emp 
(
 EmpId bigint PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
    DEFAULT (NEXT VALUE FOR EmpIdSeq),
 X nvarchar(255) NULL,
 Y nvarchar(255) NULL
);
```

---

**Update:** The above solution is only applicable to SQL Server 2012+. For older versions you can simulate the sequence behavior using dummy tables with identity fields:

```
CREATE TABLE EmpIdSeq (
 SeqID bigint IDENTITY PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED
);
```

And procedures that emulates `NEXT VALUE`:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE GetNewSeqVal_Emp
  @NewSeqVal bigint OUTPUT
AS
BEGIN
  SET NOCOUNT ON
  INSERT EmpIdSeq DEFAULT VALUES

  SET @NewSeqVal = scope_identity()

  DELETE FROM EmpIdSeq WITH (READPAST)
END;
```

Usage exemple:

```
DECLARE @NewSeqVal bigint
EXEC GetNewSeqVal_Emp @NewSeqVal OUTPUT
```

The performance overhead of deleting the last inserted element will be minimal; still, as pointed out by the original author, you can optionally remove the delete statement and schedule a maintenance job to delete the table contents off-hour (trading space for performance).

Adapted from [SQL Server Customer Advisory Team Blog](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/sqlcat/archive/2006/04/10/sql-server-sequence-number.aspx).

---

**[Working SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/740ce/1)**

Comment: SEQUENCE was introduced in SQL Server 2012 so is of little use here.

Comment: I have edited the question and entered the code i am currently using, but to enter Id's in key value pair tables or link tables (m*n relations) are the problem.

Comment: In this code if i get the next Id from one place in code and then i get the next Id from another place in code then the Id's are not synchronised.i mean if from one place in code i get 3 time next Id then from another place in code these three increments are not considered.

Comment: Sequences are kept up to date internally, much like IDENTITY columns. You don't need to worry about the next value - even three different threads will get different values.

Comment: I haven't noticed the database version, sorry. Well, how about using  separate tables, each with their own IDENTITY fields to emulate sequences? Check out option 2 from [this article](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/sqlcat/archive/2006/04/10/sql-server-sequence-number.aspx) at [SQL Server Customer Advisory Team blog](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/sqlcat/)

Comment: Khalid, I've updated the answer with a procedure that outputs bigints for legacy versions of SQL Server (the original strategy could only return ints) and a working fiddle. Does it fit your needs?

Comment: Thank you Anthony. I cannot believe that I had left this thread open. I am extremely sorry. At that time I had used this strategy and it had worked for me. Sorry again.

Answer (score 2):

The above

```
select max(empid) + 1 from employee
```

is the way to get the next number, but if there are multiple user inserting into the database, then context switching might cause two users to get the same value for empid and then add 1 to each and then end up with repeat ids.  If you do have multiple users, you may have to lock the table while inserting. This is not the best practice and that is why the auto increment exists for database tables.

Answer (score 0):

I hope this works for you. Considering that your ID field is an integer

```
INSERT INTO Table WITH (TABLOCK)
(SELECT CASE WHEN MAX(ID) IS NULL 
  THEN 1 ELSE MAX(ID)+1 END FROM Table), VALUE_1, VALUE_2....
```

Comment: we have more then one user what do you think well there be any concurrency issues in the insertion from different users at the same time.?

Comment: see the edit for table lock and checl for no records in the table

Comment: This will cause amazingly bad problems for concurrency, especially as the data grows.

Answer (score -1):

Try following query

```
INSERT INTO Table VALUES 
((SELECT isnull(MAX(ID),0)+1 FROM Table), VALUE_1, VALUE_2....)
```

you have to check isnull in on max values otherwise it will return null in final result when table contain no rows .

Comment: Hiren, while [this article](http://jeffkemponoracle.com/2012/03/22/generating-unique-identifiers-with-select-maxid-1/) (by [Jeffrey Kemp](http://stackoverflow.com/users/103295/jeffrey-kemp)) is written for Oracle Databases, the **Don't do it** warning and the mentioned reasons are applicable to SQL Server as well.

Comment: in question user clearly specified that he used SQL Server 2008 .

Comment: Which is subject to the same [racing conditions](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/698366/how-to-avoid-a-database-race-condition-when-manually-incrementing-pk-of-new-row) and performance overheads as Oracle when using `MAX(ID) + 1`.

Comment: I think this one of the solution but it want help you then just ignore it rather then vote down . it decrease the moral to help anyone .